# How to change the X Axis labels programatically on ASP.Net chart control?

Tags: asp.net, charts

I have a line chart that I am building from a SQL Data Reader which is filled from stored procedure with begin and end date parameters.

When the chart is drawn the X axis lables are the day part of the date and time string that are returned. What I would like to do is change that to the hours portion when the range is less than 24 hours.

How do I go about changing the X Axis labels?
TIA

John

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the code right in front of me but you should be able to do this via something like:

```
chart.ChartArea(0).AxisX.CustomLabels.Add
```